# How to convert css url to base64?

Tags: css, url, base64

How to convert css url to base64

like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css;base64,Ym9keSB7IHdpZHRoOiA5NjBweDsgbWFyZ2luOiBhdXRvO30gcCB7IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiBWZXJkYW5hO30" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an url, this is the entire base64 encoded css. You can encode and decode the css file here: [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/) or with notepad++ mime-tools.

Comment: Thank you for yor reply , but can you please explain more details , how i can used it?

Comment: You can convert whole files, like stylesheets or images, to base64 strings. Or you can just convert strings or file contents to base64. E.g., you can go to http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp, upload a file or insert some content, and the converter will give you a base64 string back. That string can now be embedded into your HTML like in your example. Also have a look at the following page: http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html